# Spring MVC Url Pattern Issue

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have an existing application ..where we have some jsp..in view folder of the 
application Context.Now we need to migrate one of the JSP's to a spring mvc controller..

I was doing a sample application and this is what i observed...

if I have the pattern in web-xml as / and annotate the controller as

```
RequestMapping(value="/view/Track.jsp")
```

This doesnt work..but If I modify it as /view and

update it as

```
RequestMapping(value="Track.jsp") then it works..
```

What is the reason for this..and what should be the approach for the migration.

Comment: What view resolvers have you got set up?

Comment: <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"> With JSTLView

Answer (score 0):

Spring MVC concatenates the mapping from the controller and the method. With your second mapping it results in: `/view/Track.jsp` - this is OK. When the mapping on th controller is `/view/Track.jsp` you probably don't have mapping on the method, right? That way spring don't know which method of the controller to call even if you got only one...
If you want to use only the mapping on the controller you can place `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)` on the method.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/view/Track.jsp")
public class UserController {

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String track( MapModel model ) {...}


}
```

Good practice is to use the mapping on the controller to "modulaize" your mappings if you got more controllers. That way you will prevent collision on the method mappings between controllers.